# NameError: name 'member' is not defined

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been trying to create a Discord command that adds a role based of one that is already created and am not that great at python, whenever i try to run

```
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext.commands import bot
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def pine(ctx):
    role = get(member.guild.roles, name="bot")
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.channel.purge(1)
```

but always get the error "NameError: name 'member' is not defined"
i have tried changing member to user and i get name 'user' is not defined.

Comment: Yes, `member` isn't defined, nor is `user`. What do you *expect* those names to refer to?

Comment: You have to get the member object out of the context argument

Comment: sorry again i am very new to python and am still not sure what you mean. could you go into a little more detail?

Comment: You need to spend more time learning the basics of the language before trying to make big leaps in advanced topics. Best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the variable `member` and it is not defined or imported anywhere.

Comment: how would i go about defining it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't define who is member.

```
async def xyz(ctx, member:discord.Member):
```

This command is be like: I give a rank, but I don't know who, maybe me, maybe not.